# Secure UDP broadcast with username and password using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, vlc

Is there any way to have a secure UDP broadcast with FFmpeg by requesting username and password.

I've used this command to broadcast

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -rtbufsize 702000K -framerate 30 -i video="Video (00-0 Pro Capture Quad HDMI)" -r 30 -threads 4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -f mpegts "udp://192.168.1.12:6666"
```

and I received it by open VLC using this

```
udp://@192.168.1.12:6666
```

How to provide a username and password to open this broadcast ???

Answer (score 1):

It may work for you...

**Stream**

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -rtbufsize 702000K -framerate 30 -i video="Video (00-0 Pro Capture Quad HDMI)" -r 30 -threads 4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -f mpegts "udp://username:password@192.168.1.12:6666"
```

---

**Open**

```
udp://username:password@192.168.1.12:6666
```